# How to install scrapyd on linux mint?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation

I wanted to deploy the scrapy spider written with python. Refering the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/ubuntu.html) it tells me to install scrapyd ubuntu package. But there's no additional resources in the docs.

Is there any way to install it from other sources ?

Answer (score 1):

> Refering the documentation it tells me to install scrapyd ubuntu package

No, it doesn't. The documentation says "if you're in the special position to be running ubuntu...", but you're *not* running Ubuntu.

---

Well, `scrapyd` is a pretty normal pip-packaged piece of software. So, you can pretty directly install it using pip:

```bsh
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install --user scrapyd
```

That's it. By the way, you're looking at the **drastically** outdated documentation for Scrapy 1.0; you'll want to read the current documentation (2.5 today), https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/ . And that's the scrapy, not the scrapy**d** documentation you've been looking at. The Scrapyd docs can be found on https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

Answer (score 0):

On Linux Mint it is packaged under `python3-scrapy` name from `universe` repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-scrapy
```